# Google analytics measurement protocol authentication

Tags: google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I do not understand the reason for not having OAuth flow while using the measurement protocol. The user needs the track-id for sending the request, and there are possibilities of ghosting as well. So why is OAuth process not being used for authentication in Google Analytics. Could anybody help me in understanding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measurement protocol is an http request to a URL with querystring parameters. It does not require authentication. I agree that the data can get dirty, however its operation is that.

Comment: is there an alternative for measurement protocol that uses OAuth flow to send events to Google Analytics

Comment: No, the measurement protocol is the basis. Instead you can work on the view and insert spam filters.